# Polymer 1.x - changes to the nested array in an array do not reflect in template

Tags: polymer

I have a property "dataArray" of type array in a polymer component. This array has another array "items".  I am using dom-repeat to loop through "dataArray" and also have a nested dom-repeat to loop through "items" array of each object in "dataArray".

dataArray looks like

```
[{'name': 'abc', items: [{'name': 'abc1'} , {'name': 'abc2'}]}, 
 {'name': 'xyz', items: [{'name': 'xyz1'} , {'name': 'xyz2'}]}
]

dataArray: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
             return [];
          },
          notify: true
        }

observers: [_dataArrayChanged(dataArray.*)']
```

template:

```
<template class="" is="dom-repeat" items="{{dataArray}}" as="d">
       <p> {{d.name}} </p>
       <template class="" is="dom-repeat" items="{{d.items}}" as="item">
            <p>{{item.name}}</p>
       </template>
</template>
```

When component is loaded first time, it works fine.

When 'dataArray' changed, changes are not reflected in the nested "dom-repeat".

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you set the new values? Also, you don't need `notify: true` because it only tells the parent element that this property has changed.

Comment: In Polymer 1.x you need to use specific methods for making observable changes for subproperties - read more about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data). In your example try to use `this.set('dataArray.1.name', 'newName')`

Comment: @Rickard Elimää, I tried removing notify:true, it didn't work.

Comment: @jdepypere, thanks for your response. I have an observer on this 'dataArray'. Within this observer method, if I try setting the new value to the 'dataArray' using this.set('dataArray', newVal.value), will it be in infinite loop?  Also, how can set the sub property "items" for each of the element in the parent array 'dataArray'?  Should I loop through?

Comment: @user3701057: You answered the wrong thing. Can you please update your post and tell us how you set the new values?

Comment: @Rickard Elimää, which one I did answer wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [polymer's doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data) :

> If you manipulate an array using the native methods (like
>   Array.prototype.push), you can notify Polymer after the fact.
>
> Every Polymer element has the following array mutation methods
>   available:
>
> - push(path, item1, [..., itemN])
> - pop(path)
> - unshift(path, item1, [..., itemN])
> - shift(path)
> - splice(path, index, removeCount, [item1, ..., itemN])
>
> Whenever possible **you should always use Polymer's array mutation
>   methods**. However, this isn't always possible. For example, you may be
>   using a third-party library that does not use Polymer's array mutation
>   methods. In these scenarios you can call notifySplices after each
>   mutation to ensure that any Polymer elements observing the array are
>   properly notified of the changes.

So, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caribouflex/ben8L3cL/2/) to give you an example :

For an array like yours  :

```
dataArray: {
      type: Array,
      value: function(){
        return [
          {
            name: 'abc', 
            items: [
              {'name': 'abc1'} , 
              {'name': 'abc2'}
            ]
          }, 
          {
            name: 'xyz', 
            items: [
              {'name': 'xyz1'} , 
              {'name': 'xyz2'}
            ]
          }
        ];
      }
    }
```

There is two possibilities to add a value

1) With the Polymer's arrau mutation methods :

```
   addArray:function(){
    this.push('dataArray',{
      name: 'new', 
      items: [
        {'name': 'new1'} , 
        {'name': 'new2'}
      ]
    });
  }

  removeArray:function(){
    this.splice('dataArray', this.dataArray.length-1, 1);
  }
```

And using the native methods :

```
   addArray2:function(){
    this.dataArray.push({
      name: 'new', 
      items: [
        {'name': 'new1'} , 
        {'name': 'new2'}
      ]
    });
    this.notifySplices('dataArray');
  }

  removeArray2:function(){
    this.dataArray.splice(this.dataArray.length-1, 1);
    this.notifySplices('dataArray');
  }
```

It's the same for Polymer 2.0 if I make no mistakes. (except the syntax)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Couple of questions. In your fiddle, I see you used Polymer 2.x. I am using Polymer 1.10.x, does it make any difference? Also, I have an observer on this 'dataArray'. Within this observer method, if I try setting the new value to the 'dataArray' using Polymer's methods (this.push etc...), will it be in infinite loop?

Comment: @user3701057 Oh yes I forgot to change the import version.. So Polymer's array mutation method will still work in v1.x but I think the `notifySplices()` function will need another parameter to describe the changes. You can find the function [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-notifySplices). In the observer if you set a value under you observer path (dataArray.* => everything under dataArray that change) yes you will be in a loop.